# Uncaught TypeError: UICtrl.getInput is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, node-modules, es6-modules

I want to get the inputs from the **UIController module** and log it into my main **appController** file. But I'm getting this error shown below. Can anyone please help me out?

### This is the *UI Controller* module:

```js
export default function UIController() {
    return {
        // get inputs
        getInput: function () {
            return {
                type: document.querySelector(".add__type").value,
                description: document.querySelector(".add__description").value,
                value: document.querySelector(".add__value").value,
            };
        },
    };
}
```

### This is the main file *app Controller*:

```js
// Import modules
import UIController from "./UIController.js";

// App controller
((UICtrl) => {
    function ctrlAddItem() {
        // get input data
        let input = UICtrl.getInput();
        console.log(input);
    }

    document.querySelector(".add__btn").addEventListener("click", ctrlAddItem);
})(UIController);
```

### This is the exact error I'm getting in the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: UICtrl.getInput is not a function
at HTMLButtonElement.ctrlAddItem (appController.js:9)
```

Comment: Use the: ```import { UIController } from "./UIController.js"```; Use the object destructor to point to the UIController function.

Comment: didn't work....

Comment: Please use the following link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-importing-exporting/ it will help you decide which is your best way to export a function. In general I recommend using: ```module.exports = { // Define your exports here. }```  and also please make sure that you import from the correct file level when using the import. Is the ```./UIController.js``` really in the same folder as the app Controller? probably yes, but just verify it.

Comment: By the way, I am not sure that the default definition is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are returning `function` from `UiController` module.

So you will have to add paranthesis`()` like so `let input = UICtrl().getInput();` in your main app Controller.